# Python - check for combination of items in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists of tuples: The first (A) has the value sets I'm checking. The second (B) has combinations of values that I want to weed out if they're present in A.

```
A = [(1, 2, 3), (6, 10, 8)]
B = [(5, 7, 9), (10, 6)]
```

As you can see, the checking is complicated by the facts that:
- the B tuples may be shorter than the A tuples
- the B tuples may vary in length
- the values may appear in a different order in a B tuple than they do in an A tuple
- the A tuples all have identical length but that length can't be predetermined

The best way I have come up with to do this involves some redundancy:

```
bad_tuples = [tup for badtup in B for tup in A 
              if [baditem for baditem in badtup if baditem in tup]
              and len([baditem for baditem in badtup if baditem in tup]) == len(badtup)]
good_tuples = [tup for tup in A if tup not in bad_tuples]
```

I think this gets the job done, but I don't like the fact that I have to duplicate an identical list comprehension in finding bad_tuples. I also find it hard to read and so error-prone. So can anyone think of a more elegant/efficient way of accomplishing the task?

(If it matters, in my application there are likely to be many (but < 100) tuples in A and only a few (< 10) tuples in B.)

Comment: Are the entries in each tuple unique?  Converting them to sets would simplify this, but would obviously only work if the entries were unique in each tuple.

Comment: The individual items can appear in more than one tuple, but each combination (so the value of each tuple) is unique within each list. List A is the result of itertools.product() with an indeterminate number of lists provided as arguments. But it is possible that the same item could appear in more than one of the input lists, in which case some A tuples could have more than one item with the same value. (Is that a convoluted enough answer?)

Comment: Thanks, and on that basis is the tuple `(1, 2)` different from `(1, 1, 2)`?  i.e. does the fact that `1` is in `(1, 1, 2)` twice make mean that you don't want to exclude it from A even if `(1, 2)` is in B?

Comment: No, I want to exclude any A tuple that has the same combination of values, no matter what other values are present. So the B tuple (1, 2) should exclude (1, 1, 2) as well as (2, 1, 3) or (1, 3, 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If entries within a tuple are indeed unique, it should be as simple as:

```
[x for x in A if set(x) not in [set(y) for y in B]]
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments, it appears that the exclusion should be for all tuples in A of which tuples in B are subsets when everything has been converted to sets.  So it's:

```
[x for x in A if not any([set(y).issubset(set(x)) for y in B])]
```

Comment: I just added a comment above explaining that there might be duplicate values within a tuple. But this is so much simpler that I might try to refactor the surrounding logic to make the tuples fit.

Comment: Silly me. I just realized that given my elaborations in the comments above, it doesn't matter whether the items in a tuple are unique. (i.e., I'm only looking for the presence of a combination of values, in any order, any number of times, so set() should work fine.)

Comment: Thanks. That's brilliant. I didn't even know about the issubset() method for sets. (Off to read the docs.)

Comment: Is the any() necessary? It looks to me like the contained list comprehension will evaluate True if any matches are found and False otherwise, so the any() isn't needed.

Comment: A list containing only the values `False` will actually evaluate to `True`, so you do need the `any()`, I'm afraid.  `if [False]:` will execute the following instruction, whereas `if any([False]):` will not (and so on).

Comment: Ah, right. I was forgetting that issubset() would add a False value to the list if it didn't find a match.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
for tup in B:
    if(tup in A):
        bad_tuples.append(tup)
    else:
        good_tuples.append(tup)
```

Assumed, the order of the elements of the tuples is relevant.

Comment: Thanks. That's the real trick, though. The order of elements is not relevant and I want to filter out tuples from A that have the same *combination* of values from a B tuple, even if there are other values present. (See my clarification in the comments above.)

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. Then I have to think again about it.